# How to retrieve Ads Action Stats data with Facebook Marketing API

Tags: php, facebook-marketing-api

I was trying to get insights of my campaigns. I was able to get click,impressions,spend but i also need conversions. I haven't found any example how to use fields with list< AdsActionStats >.

```
< CAMPAIGN_ID >/insights?fields=impressions,spend,clicks,ctr,conversions
```

```
  $campaign = $fb->get(
    $campaign['id'].'/insights?fields=impressions,spend,clicks,ctr,conversions',
    $access_token
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversions will be under "actions" and "actions_values," as in:

```
$campaign = $fb->get(
    $campaign['id'].'/insights?fields=impressions,spend,clicks,ctr,actions,actions_values',
    $access_token
  );
```

This will return a nested array with the length of the number of action types (including conversions) being tracked. These can be any of the ones on the [action type list linked here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/)